# Can I change bottom border line color of textfields in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, border

I want to change border color of textfield.

```
   textField1.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
```

this code is change all border color (up, bottom, right, left border). But I want to set only bottom border color. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the border color of the textfield, instead you get a image with the design you want and set it as your textfield's background image